# How can I verify token google recaptcha 3 on adonis js?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, recaptcha, adonis.js

I using vue as my front end. I send token from my front end like this :

```
let payload = {
    token: tokenCaptcha
}

axios.post(`http://127.0.0.1:3333/api/v1/category`, payload)
    .then(response => {
        return response.data
    }).catch(
    error => {
        console.log(error)
    })
```

The token will used to verify on the backend. My backend using adonis.js

The script of controller like this :

```
'use strict'
class CategoryController {
  async store ({ request, response }) {
    return request.input('token')
  }
}
module.exports = CategoryController
```

My routes like this :

```
Route.group(()=>{
  Route.post('category', 'CategoryController.store')
}).prefix('api/v1')
```

How can I verify the token on adonis.js(backend)?

I had search reference. But I don't find it

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `axios`. Something like:

```js
const axios = use('axios')
const Env = use('Env')
const querystring = use('querystring')

async store({ request, response }) {
  const data = request.only(['token'])

  try {
    const data_request = await axios.post('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify', querystring.stringify({ secret: Env.get('RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY'), response: data['token'], remoteip: '172.217.23.110' }))
    if (!data_request.data.success) {
      //If the recaptcha check fails
      ...
    }
  } catch (error) {
    ...
  }
}
```

[Google documentation - Verifying the user's response](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify)

This code is made for v2. But the verification is the same : https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/v3#site_verify_response

Comment: Seems it must to use parameter `remoteip` too

Comment: It also seems necessary to add a bodyparser. I hope you answer in full

Comment: I updated the answer. Tell me if everything's okay.